# Can Vim Omnicomplete suggest Sass variables from a ctags file?

Tags: vim, sass, omnicomplete

While editing a Sass file, I'd like to be able to use Vim's Omnicompletion (`<C-x><C-o>`) to complete Sass variables that are present in the project's ctags file.

It seems that my `~/.ctags` file is configured correctly, because when I type something like `:tag primary`, it takes me to the Sass file in which I've defined the variable `$primary`. But typing `color: $prim`, followed by `<C-x><C-o>`, gives me the message "Pattern not found."

To try to make this work, I've added the following lines to my `~/.vimrc`:

```
au FileType scss set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
set tags=tags;
```

What else do I need to do for Vim to recognize this as the beginning of a Sass variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default CSS omni-completion function, called when you do `<C-x><C-o>`, doesn't use tags at all.

Try `<C-x><C-]>` to use your `tags` file exclusively or `<C-n>` to complete from a variety of sources, including your `tags` file.

(Would you mind sharing your `~/.ctags`, please?)

Comment: The relevant portion of my `~/.ctags` file, cobbled together a while back: http://pastebin.com/4b1p4Qsp

Comment: No problem -- If you know of any way to improve that syntax let me know.